# Ajax call not waiting for server response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wamp

I am using WAMP v.2.5 on a Windows10 machine. My project is a PHP project running off a MySQL DB. It includes numerous AJAX calls, which work fine. I have one specific call however which is giving me a 'Unexpected end of input' error.

The call is made from a View, is directed to a global ajax handler PHP script which forwards the request to the Controller, which then asks the Model for the response. The appropriate Model method is being fired. The method contains error checking and will throw exceptions for an empty result. The DB Query within is valid, and returns results when used in the console. 9 times out of 10 however, the ajax fn will complete without receiving / reading the result of the query and thus generates the above error. Sometimes it will work fine.

When placed on a live server, everything works as it should. It's almost as if the script was running too quickly on the local machine to wait for the DB response or for any exception to be thrown.

Can anyone tell me how to properly test what's happening, or have a solution to the above problem?

EDIT:
Trail of affected code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //some code
    updateFilteredScheduleList();
    //some code
});

function updateFilteredScheduleList()
{
    var opts = $.extend(true, {}, dialogOptions);
    getFilteredScheduleResults()
        .done(function(returnedData)
        {
            var returnedDataObj = parseAjaxJSONResponse(returnedData);

            if(returnedDataObj.hasOwnProperty('success'))
                buildScheduleList(returnedDataObj.response);
        })
        .error(function(xhr, options, error)
        {
            opts.message = error;
            displayDialog(opts);
            return false;
        });
}

function getFilteredScheduleResults()
{
    var values = getFilterValues();
    values.controller = 'WSVisits';
    values.method = 'getFilteredScheduleResults';

    console.log(values);

    return $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        data: values,
        url: controllersAjaxPath
    });
}

function getFilterValues()
{
    var values = {};
    //get values of view filters
    return values;
}

function parseAjaxJSONResponse(data)
{
    var opts = $.extend(true, {}, dialogOptions);
    try
    {
        var tmp = JSON.parse(data);
        if(tmp.hasOwnProperty('error'))
        {
            opts.message = tmp.error;
            displayDialog(opts);
            return false;
        }

        return tmp;
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        opts.message = e.message;
        displayDialog(opts);
        return false;
    }
}
```

PHP method (slightly edited):

```
function getFilteredScheduleResults($args = null)
{
    $id = intval($args['MyID']);
    $region_id = (!$id) ? ( intval($args['RegionID']) > 0) ? intval($args['RegionID']) : 0 : 0;
    $county_id = (!$id) ? ( intval($args['CountyID']) > 0) ? intval($args['CountyID']) : 0 : 0;
    $language_id = (!$id) ? ( intval($args['LanguageID']) > 0) ? intval($args['LanguageID']) : 0 : 0;
    $center_id = (!$id) ? ( intval($args['CenterID']) > 0) ? intval($args['CenterID']) : 0 : 0;
    $type_id = (!$id) ? ( intval($args['TypeID']) > 0) ? intval($args['TypeID']) : 0 : 0;
    $support_type_id = (!$id) ? ( intval($args['SupportTypeID']) > 0) ? intval($args['SupportTypeID']) : 0 : 0;

    $address_token = (!$id) ? ( trim($args['AddressContains']) !== '') ? trim($args['AddressContains']) : null : null;

    $purpose_id = (intval($args['PurposeID']) > 0) ? intval($args['PurposeID']) : 0;
    $associate_id = (intval($args['AssociateID']) > 0) ? intval($args['AssociateID']) : 0;
    if(!empty($args['From']))
    {
        $from_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $args['From']);
        $args['From'] = (!$from_obj) ? null : $from_obj->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    if(!empty($args['To']))
    {
        $to_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $args['To']);
        $args['To'] = (!$to_obj) ? null : $to_obj->format('Y-m-d');
    }


    $sql = " /*query*/ WHERE 1 ";

    if($id)
        $sql.= " AND ( s.MyID = :MyID ) ";
    else
    {
        if($region_id)
            $sql.= " AND ( RegionID = :RegionID ) ";
        if($county_id)
            $sql.= " AND ( CountyID = :CountyID ) ";
        if($language_id)
            $sql.= " AND ( LanguageID = :LanguageID ) ";
        if($center_id)
            $sql.= " AND ( CenterID = :CenterID ) ";
        if($type_id)
            $sql.= " AND ( s.TypeID = :TypeID ) ";
        if($support_type_id)
            $sql.= " AND ( SupportTypeID = :SupportTypeID ) ";";
        if(!is_null($address_token))
            $sql.= " AND ( UPPER(CONCAT_WS(' ', Add1, Add2, Add3, CityTown)) LIKE UPPER(:AddressToken) ) ";
    }

    $sql.= " GROUP BY s.MyID ORDER BY MyName ASC ";

    $db = new Database();
    try
    {
        $db->query($sql);
        if($id)
            $db->bind(':MyID', $id);
        else
        {
            if($region_id)
                $db->bind(':RegionID', $region_id);
            if($county_id)
                $db->bind(':CountyID', $county_id);
            if($language_id)
                $db->bind(':LanguageID', $language_id);
            if($center_id)
                $db->bind(':CenterID', $center_id);
            if($type_id)
                $db->bind(':TypeID', $type_id);
            if($support_type_id)
                $db->bind(':SupportTypeID', $support_type_id);
            if(!is_null($address_token))
                $db->bind(':AddressToken', '%' . $address_token . '%');
        }
        $db->execute();
        $tmp = $db->fetchAllAssoc();

        $get_assignments_only = (!empty($args['AssignmentsOnly']));
        $returned = [];

        $sql = " SELECT VisitID FROM visits_ws WHERE MyID = :MyID ";
        if($purpose_id)
            $sql.= " AND ( VisitPurposeID = :Purpose ) ";
        if($associate_id)
            $sql.= " AND ( ( Associate1ID = :AssociateID ) OR ( Associate2ID = :AssociateID ) OR ( Associate3ID = :AssociateID ) OR ( Associate4ID = :AssociateID ) ) ";
        if(!empty($args['From']))
            $sql.= " AND ( VisitDate >= :From ) ";
        if(!empty($args['To']))
            $sql.= " AND ( VisitDate <= :To ) ";
        $db->query($sql);

        foreach($tmp as $i => $t)
        {
            $db->bind(':MyID', $t['MyID']);
            if($purpose_id)
                $db->bind(':Purpose', $purpose_id);
            if($associate_id)
                $db->bind(':AssociateID', $associate_id);
            if(!empty($args['From']))
                $db->bind(':From', $args['From']);
            if(!empty($args['To']))
                $db->bind(':To', $args['To']);
            $db->execute();
            $visits = $db->fetchAllAssoc();

            if( ($get_assignments_only) && (empty($visits)) )
                continue;

            if( ( ($purpose_id) || ($associate_id) || (!empty($args['From'])) || (!empty($args['To'])) ) && (empty($visits)) )
                continue;

            $tmp[$i]['HasVisits'] = (empty($visits)) ? 0 : 1;
            $tmp = $schools[$i];
            unset($tmp['Name']);
            $schools[$i]['Address'] = build_address($tmp);

            unset($schools[$i]['Add1']);
            unset($schools[$i]['Add2']);
            unset($schools[$i]['Add3']);
            unset($schools[$i]['CityTown']);
            unset($schools[$i]['CityPostCode']);
            unset($schools[$i]['Name']);
            unset($schools[$i]['LanguageID']);

            unset($schools[$i]['PrincipalID']);
            unset($schools[$i]['ContactID']);
            unset($schools[$i]['TypeID']);
            unset($schools[$i]['CenterID']);
            unset($schools[$i]['SupportTypeID']);
            unset($schools[$i]['CountyID']);
            unset($schools[$i]['AreaCodeID']);
            unset($schools[$i]['NetworkCodeID']);
            unset($schools[$i]['RegionID']);

            $returned[] = $tmp[$i];
        }

        return ['jct_success'=>'ok', 'response'=>$returned];
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        return ['jct_error'=>$e->getMessage()];
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me your ajax code?

Comment: Please add you jquery code that include AJAX call.

Comment: @Plum I added the jquery functions concerned. I will add the PHP method also...

Comment: the return false in .error is useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the culprit:

I had to update my Apache max_input_vars to a higher limit to allow the number of individual parameters being returned to actually *be* returned. Post size was not the issue.